# Jenkins MultiJob Plugin- "Phases" option not available in Build Section

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We're using Jenkins for deployment, and would like to use the [Jenkins MultiJob plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) to deploy a bunch of services at once. From the description, it looks like this will do exactly what we want. I have the latest version of the plugin (currently 1.9) and all other plugins and Jenkins are up to date. 
On the [plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin), it says this: *This job can define in the Build section phases that contains one job or more.*, and it shows a screen print with the ability to configure phases and jobs. But, I don't see that option anywhere after I create a new MultiJob project (which is step one in their process). I have restarted Jenkins in case something wasn't right. 
I'm hoping someone can help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste the page that you *do* see when you create a new MultiJob project ?  You should also look in the Jenkins log to see if it threw an error when you created the new project.

Answer (score 2):

I had reboot Jenkins, and still could not find it.

I finally found it under "Add Build Step" -> MultiJob Phase

Answer (score 1):

OK, figured it out. For some reason, I cannot get the "phases" option to show up on the original MultiJob that I created before restarting Jenkins, although it told me that the feature would be available without a restart.

I created a new MultiJob project (after the Jenkins restart), and I now have the phases option available, and is working.
Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I have the same issue, too, but in my case "Phases" do not show up as a "Build Step" even after restarting Jenkins and creating a new Multi-Job.

Comment: I had to scroll down a lot to get "MultiJob Phase" in the "Add build step" context menu.